# attach image from camera to email - android

Tags: android, email, android-camera

I have a button which takes a photo, stores the thumbnail in an Imageview, and when the user clicks another button, it needs to attach that image to an email.

Ive followed the "Taking Photos Simply" directions from the Android site, but there is no attachment included. Can somebody see where i am going wrong, and what I need to do to fix it?

My on Activity Result code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
        if (requestcode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap BMB;
                BMB = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                Hoon_Image.setImageBitmap(BMB);
                try {
                    createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mDrawable = Hoon_Image.getDrawable();
                mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mDrawable).getBitmap();
            }
        }
    }

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

my email intent:

```
if (Witness_response == "Yes"){
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"roadsafety.app@shellharbour.nsw.gov.au"});
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Dob in a Hoon Report (Y)");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hoon report has been recieved " + emailBody);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mCurrentPhotoPath );
                    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose email client..."));
                } else if (Witness_response == "No"){
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"roadsafety.app@shellharbour.nsw.gov.au"});
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Dob in a Hoon Report (N)");
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hoon report has been recieved " + emailBody);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose email client..."));
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
private ImageView imageView;
private File f;
public File getAlbumDir()
{

    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
            ), 
            "BAC/"
        ); 
     // Create directories if needed
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        storageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    return storageDir;
}
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name

    String imageFileName =getAlbumDir().toString() +"/image.jpg";
    File image = new File(imageFileName);
    return image;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                f = createImageFile();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  

        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"email id"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }  
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 

emailIntent.setType("image/*");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"me@gmail.com"}); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test Subject"); 
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"go on read the emails");     
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Mail"));;
```

and here,

```
uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FILENAME));
```

Comment: how do you implement this?

Comment: what ? can you please xplain what you want to know ? are you got solution from this ?